# CSS hover show text at specific position

Tags: html, css, image

I want to make only the text of the hovered image visible, and it should be in the grey space next (left/right) to the hovered picture (not under the picture outside of the grey space).

Is that possible only with css?

If not what do I need ? javascript?

**HTML**

```
<div class="pictures">
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pic">
        <img class="inner-img" src="http://www.csstutorial.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/045.png"/><p>This is a beautiful flower!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pictures {
    background-color:rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    --width: 960px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    left:100px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.pictures:hover {
    left:40px;
}
.pic {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-color:rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.7);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    color:blue;
    border-radius: 3px;
    /*abgerundete Ecken*/
}
.pic:hover {
    width:210px;
    height:210px;
    margin:5px 115px 0px -105px;
    right: -110px;
}
.inner-img {
    width:100%;
}
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vloxxity/BCvPk/) the working example.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so a couple things here:

1. Your image is too large, in that there are transparent pixels forcing that text out of the dark grey box. Make the image only as large as it needs to be, then nest it in a container element with some padding or something to achieve a similar effect.
2. If the effect you're looking for is to have no text visible until you hover, then yes. Just add a `display:none` to the text then add a selector like `.image-container:hover p { display:inline-block; }` or you could use css3 opacity and fade it in, though that would be ugly since it's already scaling up, you don't want it fading in as well probably.
3. If the effect your desiring is NOT the one described above, you can use jQuery and easily achieve it. Say you want all text visible then on hover you want every other image's text gone, just have `$('.image-container').hover(function(){//hide all text but the text nested in current element receiving the hover event });`

Let me know if you have questions regarding specific implementation, but that should be fine to get you started

Comment: The text should not be in the dark grey box it should be in the light grey box next to the dark grey box.
And only the one text of the hovered picture should be visible.

Comment: Okay then just position it wherever you need it to eventually be then hide all the nested <p> tags except on the hover state of it's parent element `.pic`